# Difference between returning IHttpActionResult and returning an object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api, postman

When witting APIs I usually write them where I return a method from the IHttpActionResult interface (such as OK()) and have the returned object placed as a parameter inside the OK() method. Or I can just return the object I've retrieved from the database.

Example code: Using **IHttpActionResult**

```
[Route("GetAll1")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAll1()
{
    List<ContactWebLink> contactWebLinks = new List<ContactWebLink>();
    try
    {
         Manager<ContactWebLink> contactWebLinkManager = new Manager<ContactWebLink>(Unit);
         contactWebLinks = contactWebLinkManager.FindAll(a => a.IsDeleted == false, null, null, null);
         return Ok(contactWebLinks);
    }
    catch
    {
         return InternalServerError();
    }
    finally
    {
         contactWebLinks = null;
    }
 }
```

Vs **using the object's class I'm returning**

```
[Route("GetAll2")]
[HttpGet]
public List<ContactWebLink> GetAll2()
{
    List<ContactWebLink> contactWebLinks = new List<ContactWebLink>();
    try
    {
        Manager<ContactWebLink> contactWebLinkManager = new Manager<ContactWebLink>(Unit);
        contactWebLinks = contactWebLinkManager.FindAll(a => a.IsDeleted == false, null, null, null);
        return contactWebLinks;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        contactWebLinks = null;
    }
}
```

Using Postman to test the results, I see to difference whatsoever. both result in a 200 Response code (when no exceptions occur). Both return the same result (the entity I'm retrieving from the database).

So whats the difference between using the two methods, and when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `HTTP` status code when using `IHttpActionReslt` eg return the object and a 200 (Success), or 204 and No content, or a custom error message etc.

Eg

```
BadRequest("Item not found");//404

Ok(myObject);//200
```

Or you can specify the status code eg:

```
return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
```

Comment: Is that the only benefit I get when using IHttpActionReslt?

Comment: It seems to me that that is a big benefit

Comment: But both return the appropriate HTTP status code.

Comment: You can specify the status code yourself

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `IHttpActionResult`. Your correct that in the case of a success, there is no difference. When there is an error, you're able to give the client more information by returning a more accurate code.

For example, you use `InternalServerError` (500). You can give a richer error:

```
   return      
       ResponseMessage(
           Request.CreateErrorResponse(
               HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
               "There has been an error on the server regarding X"));
```

You can also return just about any REST code too.

Comment: I liken `IHttpActionResult` to using implicit `var` instead of explicit type. Refactoring becomes so much easier.